# AWS Credentials issue while access S3 bucket in C#

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-credentials

I set all my profile in my computer which is working in my local machine, when i try to access in aws EC2 instance it is not working, both machine "defult" profile configured, i am getting null in "basicProfile" variable

may i know what is the reason? please me to solve sooner.

```
 CredentialProfile basicProfile;
AWSCredentials awsCredentials;
var sharedFile = new SharedCredentialsFile();

  if (sharedFile.TryGetProfile("default", basicProfile) && AWSCredentialsFactory.TryGetAWSCredentials(basicProfile, sharedFile, awsCredentials))
    {
        var client = new AmazonS3Client(awsCredentials);
        var response = client.PutObject(request);
        if (response.HttpStatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: First problem: that's not C#. Please use the right tags, and don't include C# in the title if you're actually using VB. (It doesn't help that we don't know what `sharedFile` is...)

Comment: Please see [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest) (TLDR - the answer is 'never')

Comment: This code won't compile, so what is the code that actually fails?